# PHP Markdown Extra and Definition Lists

Tags: php, list, markdown, definition

I'm currently generating a definition list with PHP Markdown Extra with the following syntax:

```
Term
:   Description
:   Description Two

My Other Term
:   Description
```

which generates the following HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description Two</dd>
    <dt>My Other Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
</dl>
```

Does anyone know how I can get Markdown to create separate definition lists for each definition term and descriptions to create markup like this?

```
<dl>
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
    <dd>Description Two</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>My Other Term</dt>
    <dd>Description</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is currently possible. Try to insert some dummy element between the two DL so it doesn't treat them as one.

Comment: Thanks Ivo, I'm currently resorting to using dummy elements but it defeats the purpose of have both clean markdown and markup :D

Comment: I agree with you, try to bring the issue to the author maybe he will be interested to know.

Answer (score 1):

you can do so by remembering to the support of embedded html ;-)
Just do this:

```
Term
:   Description
:   Description Two
</dl><dl>
My Other Term
:   Description
```

And you'll get this:

```
<dl>
   <dt>Term</dt>
   <dd>Description</dd>
   <dd>Description Two</dd>
</dl><dl> <<< this is your code
   <dt>My Other Term</dt>
   <dd>Description</dd>
</dl>
```